# Регулярное выражение для preg_split (Разложение строки "photo1542_123" на массив)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста подправить регулярное выражение для функции `preg_split()`.

```
preg_split('/^(photo)*([0-9])+_/','photo1542_123')
```

Необходимо, чтобы строку `photo1542_123` разбивало на массив

```
`Array ( [0] =>photo [1] => 1542 [2] => 123 ) `.
```

Comment: Я думаю вам нужен preg_match, только там будет еще один лишний нулевой элемент со всей строкой

Comment: Mike прав. `preg_match('/^(photo)(\d+)_(\d+)$/','photo1542_123', $m)` должно вернуть то, что нужно в `$m[1]`

Comment: cyadvert Спасибо!

Comment: @wao138, А откуда строки такого формата? Не id фото в вк? Просто интересно)))

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev курсовой проект, а такой вариант хранения хранения id фотографии в html коде показался мне наиболее приемлемым ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тогда оформлю как ответ :)

```
preg_match('/^(photo)(\d+)_(\d+)$/','photo1542_123', $m)
```

вернет то, что нужно в `$m[1]`